# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2 \le \sum_{k=1}^nx_ky_k$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Let $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ be real strictly positive numbers and $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n$ numbers. We **suppose** that

$$x_1\, \ge\, x_2\,  \ge \cdots \ge\, x_n$$

For all $k \in [|1,n|] $  we have by definition $S_k=\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_i ,T_k=\sum_{i=1}^{k}y_i$ and **suppose** that

$$ \forall_{k=1\ldots n}\qquad S_k \le T_k $$

**Show** that

$$\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2\,\ \le\,\ \sum_{k=1}^nx_ky_k$$

I do have a small indication in the textbook: Choose $T_0=S_0=0$ and note that $S_k-S_{k-1}=x_k$ and $T_k-T_{k-1}=y_k$

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: A couple of notational issues: what is $[|1,n|]$? Also shouldn't it be $S_\color{red}{n}=\sum_{k=1}^nx_k$, and same for $T$?

Comment: Are you omitting some of the details from the question? Because as it stands, the statement is not true. For example, the $n=1$ case reads $$x_1^2=x_1y_1$$ which is clearly not true in general.

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake with $S_k$ and $T_k$ and by  $[|1,n|]$ I mean integers between $1$ and $n$

Comment: Do finished edits? $n=1$ still is true only for $x_1=y_1$.

Comment: Sorry it's an inequality. I'm very tired...

Comment: Thank you, Alex, for the comments under my soon non-existing "answer", where I had neglected the essential assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $x_{n+1} = 0 $.

**Hint:** Prove that for any series with $x_{n+1} = 0$,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \left[ (x_i - x_{i+1}) (\sum_{j=1}^i y_j) \right] = \sum_{j=1}^n x_j y_j. $$

> This is just a change of variables:
>  $$\sum_{i=1}^n \left[ (x_i - x_{i+1}) (\sum_{j=1}^i y_j) \right] = \sum_{j=1}^n \left[ y_j \sum_{i=j}^n(x_i - x_{i+1})\right] = \sum_{j=1}^n x_jy_j - x_{n+1}y_j = \sum_{j=1}^n x_j y_j. $$

**Corollary:** $  \sum x_i y_i - x_i^2  = \sum (x_i - x_{i+1} ) ( T_ i - S_i ) \geq 0  $, hence $ \sum x_i y_i \geq \sum x_i^2$.

---

The identity in the hint is known as "summation by parts", and is analogous to the "integration by parts" identity.

Comment: Is the analogue called summation by parts or Abel's summation formula?

Comment: @eloiprime Ah yes indeed, edited that in. Thanks, I wanted to make it clear that the identity wasn't some "magic" / crazy observation.

Comment: This is brillant! Thank you